# cocos2d-x addchild will not display child image at first time

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a button, when click the button, it will add a sprite with into the scene, but the sprite will not display the image, it is just all black, but I can see the sprite boundary, but after I minimize the window and display window again, it will be ok. what happened about this?

```
local removeSprite = mainScene:getChildByTag(tag)
mainScene:removeChild(removeSprite)

local replaceSprite = CCSprite:new("hello.png")
replaceSprite:setTag(tag)
mainScene:addChild(replaceSprite)
```

I use quick-cocos2d-x, but it is the same as the cocos2d-x c++, I first remove the old sprite, and add a new sprite.

Comment: Could you show the button callback function? Or even maybe the whole scene/layer code for this.

Comment: oh, my god, help me, stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

If mainScene is a ccscene object , then you should not do this.
ccsprite object is better added to a cclayer object and then that layer added to the scene.
Also, instead of doing this:

local removeSprite = mainScene:getChildByTag(tag);

mainScene:removeChild(removeSprite);

just do this:

mainScene:removeChildByTag(tag);

I don't know quick-cocos2dx but this is what i do in c++